# Нули при отображении даты (date) в БД MSSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, дата

У меня есть значение даты в формате 4.05.2017 при добавлении этого значения в БД MS SQL(формат столбца - date) получается 4.05.2017 00:00:00. То есть автоматически добавляется величина времени, при чем это всегда нули. Как можно избавиться от отображения времени? Спасибо.

Comment: А какой тип поля, а? небось DATETIME или иной, имеющий компоненту времени? ну так кто виноват... измените на DATE. Или убеждены, что там именно DATE? проверьте на всякий случай... А с проблемами ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ (не хранения!) данных обращайтесь не к серверу, а к тому клиенту, который их собственно отображает.

Comment: @Akina, тип поля DATE.

Comment: Ну тогда требуется просто правильное форматирование ВЫВОДА, без компоненты времени.

Comment: Не [плодите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660593/184217) темы.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, забыл что уже создавал такой вопрос)

Comment: @Akina, а как именно настроить форматирование вывода в grid view?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql, стили 104, 105 или 106. Т.е. например `CONVERT(nvarchar(10), datetimefield, 104)`. Гарантированное отображение только даты, но в формате *строка*. Или простое `CAST(datetimefield AS DATE)` - останется формат даты, но тут грид может и пошалить...

Comment: Сколько можно повторять: форматируйте дату на **клиенте**! Задайте той колонке датагрида, в которой выводится дата, свойство `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy.MM.dd"`. Ссылки на документацию: свойство [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx), форматы [даты/времени](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `ToString()`;
Если дата и время  выводятся куда-то в виде текста, то можете преобразовать так (независимо от локали):
`date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Дата выводится в таблицу. Куда конкретно нужно добавить этот код, не подскажете?

Comment: В какую таблицу? DataGrid? Это wpf?

Comment: да DataGridView, это Windows Form.